# rflex/b21 cmd_vel not working as expected

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a problem with a B21r. Here is what I did:

- Start roscore
- Start b21 drivers (rosrun rflex b21)
- Publish this message to /b21/cmd_vel:

  - rostopic pub -1 /b21/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0, 0, 0]' '[0, 0, 0.3]'

What I expect and get in simulations is that the robot turns a step and stops.

What I get with is that it takes a while until the robot starts to move, then turns, stops, turns another step, stops, and so on (with different step sizes). I watched /b21/cmd_vel, the command is only sent once. Sometimes the b21 driver prints a message like
"B21 Home 26.523571".

Is this this correct behavior and am I missing something? It would be nice if someone could explain this behavior to me. We tried navigating with ROSE, and it worked correctly, so it seems not to be a hardware issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10900/rflex/b21-cmd_vel-not-working-as-expected/) by [Tim Heinrich](https://answers.ros.org/users/954/tim-heinrich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I wrote the RFLEX driver, I tested it with the joystick teleop and navigation stacks. I had not really considered the effects of sending just one message.

When the driver recieves the Twist message, it stores the velocities and sends them to the hardware continuously. The effect I would expect from running that command is for the robot to turn in a circle indefinitely. I don't know why it stops.

The B21 Home message is leftover debug information (sorry about that) for when it hits its 'home' orientation.

I wrote the driver awhile ago. If this is not the standard behavior for working with cmd_vel commands, I can fix it. Or better yet, you can submit a patch :)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We could actually fix the problem. Having a look at the Player-implementation, we found the following:

> // ** workaround for stupid hardware
> bug, cause unknown, but this works
> // ** with minimal detriment to
> control   // ** avoids all values with
> 1b in highest or 3'rd highest order
> byte
>
> // 0x1b is part of the packet
> terminating string   // which is most
> likely what causes the bug
>
> // ** if 2'nd order byte is 1b,
> round to nearest 1c, or 1a
> if((urvel&0xff00)==0x1b00){
> // ** if lowest order byte is>127 round up, otherwise round down
> urvel=(urvel&0xffff0000)|((urvel&0xff)>127?0x1c00:0x1aff);
> }

So we also included this into the rflex_driver.cc of the rflex ROS-package and this seemed to fix the strange behaviour with the delays and the stops between the movement. Apparently i don´t have enough Karma to upload files yet, so i´ll send you a patch via mail so you can test it.

Cheers

Michi

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2011-12-12**:
A created a ticked and appended the patch!

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-11-29**:
If you create a ticket in the tracker (https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=261576&atid=1333666) and attach a patch, we can incorporate your fix.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I confirm that michikarg's fix does work.

I was also able to fix the issue 'in code' by gently ripping out the port initialization function from original player's rflex driver, and adding it to ROS rflex_driver.cc. I did not clean the code and now my driver has two redundant initializations.

To save you some time, here is the code I have added (rflex-player.hh):

```
/*
 * Functions ripped straight from player's rflex driver to fix the issue
 * with port initialization.
 */

#ifndef RFLEX_PLAYER_HH_
#define RFLEX_PLAYER_HH_

#include <rflex/rflex_info.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH                256

enum PARITY_TYPE   { N, E, O };

typedef struct {
  char                       ttyport[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
  int                        baud;
  enum PARITY_TYPE           parity;
  int                        fd;
  int                        databits;
  int                        stopbits;
  int                        hwf;
  int                        swf;
} RFLEX_Device;

// From rflex-io.cc
int iParity(enum PARITY_TYPE par) {
    if (par == N)
        return (IGNPAR);
    else
        return (INPCK);
}

int iSoftControl(int flowcontrol) {
    if (flowcontrol)
        return (IXON);
    else
        return (IXOFF);
}

int cDataSize(int numbits) {
    switch (numbits) {
    case 5:
        return (CS5);
        break;
    case 6:
        return (CS6);
        break;
    case 7:
        return (CS7);
        break;
    case 8:
        return (CS8);
        break;
    default:
        return (CS8);
        break;
    }
}

int cStopSize(int numbits) {
    if (numbits == 2) {
        return (CSTOPB);
    } else {
        return (0);
    }
}

int cFlowControl(int flowcontrol) {
    if (flowcontrol) {
        return (CRTSCTS);
    } else {
        return (CLOCAL);
    }
}

int cParity(enum PARITY_TYPE par) {
    if (par != N) {
        if (par == O) {
            return (PARENB | PARODD);
        } else {
            return (PARENB);
        }
    } else {
        return (0);
    }
}

int cBaudrate(int baudrate) {
    switch (baudrate) {
    case 0:
        return (B0);
        break;
    case 300:
        return (B300);
        break;
    case 600:
        return (B600);
        break;
    case 1200:
        return (B1200);
        break;
    case 2400:
        return (B2400);
        break;
    case 4800:
        return (B4800);
        break;
    case 9600:
        return (B9600);
        break;
    case 19200:
        return (B19200);
        break;
    case 38400:
        return (B38400);
        break;
    case 57600:
        return (B57600);
        break;
    case 115200:
        return (B115200);
        break;
#ifdef B230400
    case 230400:
        return (B230400);
        break;
#endif

    default:
        return (B9600);
        break;
    }

}

void DEVICE_set_params(RFLEX_Device dev) {
    struct termios ctio;

    tcgetattr(dev.fd, &ctio); /* save current port settings */

    ctio.c_iflag = iSoftControl(dev.swf) | iParity(dev.parity);
    ctio.c_oflag = 0;
    ctio.c_cflag = CREAD | cFlowControl(dev.hwf || dev.swf)
            | cParity(dev.parity) | cDataSize(dev.databits)
            | cStopSize(dev.stopbits);

    ctio.c_lflag = 0;
    ctio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; /* inter-character timer unused */
    ctio.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; /* blocking read until 0 chars received */

    cfsetispeed(&ctio, (speed_t) cBaudrate(dev.baud));
    cfsetospeed(&ctio, (speed_t) cBaudrate(dev.baud));

    tcflush(dev.fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(dev.fd, TCSANOW, &ctio);

}

int DEVICE_connect_port(RFLEX_Device *dev) {
    if ((dev->fd = open((dev->ttyport), (O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY), 0)) < 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    DEVICE_set_params(*dev);
    return (dev->fd);
}
// /rflex-io.h

int rflex_open_connection(const char *device_name, int *fd) {
    RFLEX_Device rdev;

    strncpy(rdev.ttyport, device_name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
    rdev.baud = 115200;
    rdev.databits = 8;
    rdev.parity = N;
    rdev.stopbits = 1;
    rdev.hwf = 0;
    rdev.swf = 0;

    printf("trying port %s\n", rdev.ttyport);
    if (DEVICE_connect_port(&rdev) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open device %s\n", rdev.ttyport);
        return -1;
    }

    *fd = rdev.fd;
    return 0;
}

#endif /* RFLEX_PLAYER_HH_ */
```

Then include the above into rflex_driver.cc and replace (in rflex_driver.cc):

```
fd = open(device_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd == -1) {
```

for

```
if (rflex_open_connection(device_name, &fd) < 0) {
```

If someone wants to go through the code and find what it does differently, then you should pay attention to DEVICE_set_params(). The part fixes the problem (removing the call makes the lag reappear). This is on my todo list, but not as urgent as other things.

---

Originally posted by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) with karma: 221 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1